# Ubuntu Lucid Lynx: blank screen AFTER login

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, display

After I did a partial upgrade, my screen went blank. I think I used an onboard graphics card, but I cannot be sure.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> at startup and did a [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) upgrade and apt-get update. It didn't work.

I am very frustrated after spending three days to get Ubuntu to work for it to kill my screen the moment I did a first update.

Comment: what's your video card? do you see anything on boot or just when X starts? can you get a console how about a rescue kernel will it boot?

Comment: Please, post /var/log/syslog and /var/log/Xorg.0.log. You can do it straight from the console with `pastebinit` Ubuntu utulity: e.g. `pastebinit </some/log`. It is located in package with the same name.